# How to round up to the next 10?

Tags: r

Is there a way in R that rounds up integer numbers to the next 10? For example all values from 0 to 9 will be converted to 10. 10 of course remains 10. Then all values from 11 to 19 are converted to 20 etc. I have founded how to round up to tne nearest 10 with: `round_to <- function(x, to = 10) round(x/to)*to`

Comment: what about 10.1 ?

Comment: Change `round(x/to)*to` to `ceiling(x/to)*to` edit: depending on your answer to what @docendo discimus asked

Comment: docendo only integers. I will edit.

Comment: @Henrik - not sure this should close as a duplicate, since this question specifies integers only.  In which case we can use interger math answers here which might be more efficient that floating point math.  E.g. `next_ten <- function(x) (x %/% 10L + as.logical(x %% 10))  * 10L`

Comment: of course it cannot be closed as duplicate since it looks for the next and not the nearest.

Comment: or with integer math again, `x + ifelse(y <- x %% 10L, 10L-y, 0)` seems quite efficient

Comment: @firmo23 Please read the title of the linked question: "round **up** to the nearest"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find an actual duplicate answer on Stack Overflow, so I am posting the following formula:

```
next_ten <- function(x) { 10*ceiling(x/10) }
v <- c(1, 5, 10, 11, 20, 29, 30, 31)
v
next_ten(v)

[1]  1  5 10 11 20 29 30 31
[1] 10 10 10 20 20 30 30 40
```

This tricks works by first finding how many tens, or decimal fractions of tens, there are (`ceiling(x/10)`).  Then, we multiply by 10, to get the effective ceiling you want.

Comment: The function name is confusing. I'd call it `next_ten`.

Comment: oh great thank you.